# Close an entire post?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23363241/escaping-backslash-in-java-string-literal/23363356#23363356), I find it is wrong (**right answer is shown in next link**) so I edit it to right version. But my edit was rejected. Then I find this question is also a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183248/how-to-replace-single-with-in-java-when-i-run-replaceall-then-error) which has better and more answers to the question (so I flag the question as duplicate).

So what else to do?

Comment: _"So What else to do?"_ Downvote wrong answer (and comment !), If you feel that is right. It has 4 votes though, and it does things very similarly to the accepted answer in your other linked question, so I would not be so quick in considering it "Wrong".

Comment: The title of second question should tell you why it is wrong.

Comment: It may be wrong (I don't really know how Java handles file paths), but from the comment by the answerer _"I don't know the use-case of the user [asker]. Maybe he is reading those paths from a file that a client can modify. "_ This suggests to me that it was answered in such a way as to solve the asker's obscure use case, which might mean that it does not work for anything (or anyone) else. This might mean that it is wrong for everyone else, but it solved the asker's problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot count on getting edits approved that fix a technical inaccuracy in a post.  That requires the reviewers to *know* that the edit is correct, there is no mechanism to ensure that edits to [java] posts are only reviewed by SO users that know Java.  So reviewers often reject the edit, unless you give them a good chance to get it right by explicitly pointing out in the edit comment why the edit was necessary.

Posting a comment on the question that suggest a duplicate looks incorrect as well.  It requires the *question* to be a duplicate, not the answer.  While they *might* try to solve the same problem, that isn't crystal from the questions.  These questions suffer from significant cargo cult, you can't often guess why a questioner intentionally appears to do the wrong thing.

Best thing to do here is to just post a comment on the answer that links to the other Q+A so the poster can fix it himself.  I took care of it.

Comment: Ok, I understand now.